# Laravel / hasMany / 3 tables single callback

Tags: laravel

I have 3 tables like so:

```
User:
- user_id
- name

Location_user:
- loc_id
- loc_loc_id
- loc_user_id

Location:
- location_id
- location_name
```

So the users may belong to 4 locations so the "location_user" table will hold 4 records for that user.

At the moment I can call the users and get back a list of there locations but on an ID only basis using:

```
public function locations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Location_user', 'loc_user_id');
}
```

As I said this will come back with all the locations this user belongs too but I want to get the names of those location instead of the ID's or even both.

Any ideas? I am fairly new to laravel still so not had to do this yet.

EDIT:

Called by:
     $results = User::with('locations')->get();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using:

```
public function locations() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Location', 'location_user', 'loc_user_id', 'loc_loc_id')->withTimestamps('loc_updated','loc_created');
}
```

Because I used custom column names I specified these and also included time-stamps as I needed those

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a many to many relationship not hasMany. Change your function to

```
public function locations()
{
  return $this->BelongsToMany('App\Location_user', 'Location_user');
}
```

Comment: Wasn't quite as simple as that, I added my usage or call for the users to the original question if that helps?

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'Location_user'

Comment: what is name of the pivot table. Meaning which table is holding the Location_user Model

Comment: huh it is Location_user should I add location with hasOne in it for the location? within the Location_user model I mean.

Comment: There is no need for the `Location_user` model. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many